# Localization Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

Hey I am relatively new to wordpress and the theme i use is not localized.

I have lines like this

```
<?php echo comments_number('no comments', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?>
```

and make it to this

```
<?php load_theme_textdomain('myLocalization'); echo comments_number(_e('no comments','myLocalization'), '1 comment', '% comments'); ?>
```

I created a .po file with [this page](http://www.icanlocalize.com/tools/create_po_from_php) and edited with the programm poedit and make all changes what have to be done in this tutorial 
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-localize-a-wordpress-theme-and-make-it-translation-ready/

But it didn't work. It will not change the string.

Can you give me a hint, where i make a failure. Has the file named to the theme name?

Comment: did you export .mo file too?

Comment: Yes both files are in the themes folder of the languages folder

Comment: what is your current language and what is your po file name?

Comment: My current language is german and my . po file is named myLocalization.po.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using German language, your .po, .mo file name should be de_DE.po, de_DE.mo.

text domain file should be {locale}.po, {locate}.mo. you can get current locale name by following wordpress function.

```
get_locale()
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the myLocalization-de_DE.po. This works. Thanks man. Thank you very much!